# building a 5 day forecast using open weather api AJAX and JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, openweathermap

I am trying to build a 5-day forecast using open weather API. The parameters I'm using based on the website are not working, it returns undefined. Also, is there a way I can get the main temp from day 1, 2 and etc. Please help

here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast', //API Call
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'GET',
  data: {
    q: city,
    appid: key,
    units: 'metric',
    cnt: '10'
  },
  success: function(data) {
    var wf = '';
    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
      wf += '<p><b>' + data.city.name + '</b><img src=http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + data.list[0].weather.icon + '.png></p>' + data.list[0].main.temp + '&deg;C' + ' | ' + data.list[0].weather.main + ", " + data.list[0].weather.description
    });
    $("#showWeatherForcast").html(wf);
  }
});
```

Comment: check this [5 day weather forecast](http://openweathermap.org/forecast5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is not too far off. I suggest that you use `console.log(data)` in your `success` function to see what pops out while you are testing. It will help you understand the returned data structure.

If you take a look in your browser console now, you will likely see some warnings. I recommend you use `https` instead of `http` URLs for both your main API call and your image URLs to avoid some of them, including Mixed Content warnings.

The below code is adapted from yours and displays a temperature, a description, and an icon per each `val` in `data.list` in `city`. Note that `$.each` here loops through properties of each `val` (0-9) in the array `data.list` to access the data you need. Your current code tries to access a `val` of `data.list[0][some property]` each time, returning `undefined`.

```
var key = "YOUR KEY";
var city = "YOUR CITY"; // My test case was "London"
var url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast";

$.ajax({
  url: url, //API Call
  dataType: "json",
  type: "GET",
  data: {
    q: city,
    appid: key,
    units: "metric",
    cnt: "10"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('Received data:', data) // For testing
    var wf = "";
    wf += "<h2>" + data.city.name + "</h2>"; // City (displays once)
    $.each(data.list, function(index, val) {
      wf += "<p>" // Opening paragraph tag
      wf += "<b>Day " + index + "</b>: " // Day
      wf += val.main.temp + "&degC" // Temperature
      wf += "<span> | " + val.weather[0].description + "</span>"; // Description
      wf += "<img src='https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + val.weather[0].icon + ".png'>" // Icon
      wf += "</p>" // Closing paragraph tag
    });
    $("#showWeatherForcast").html(wf);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the url and remove the data property

```
'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid='+key+'&q='+city+'&count=10'
```

I can't test without an api key but the docs pretty much tell you what to do http://openweathermap.org/forecast5